# Weird behaviour of \small in list environment

Tags: beamer, lists, fontsize

I am using `\small` in a list environment in Beamer and facing a problem that the text after closing of `\small` is still small. Following is a minimal working example of the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Weird behaviour of $\setminus$small in the listing env.} 
\begin{itemize}
\item This is normal text and \small{this is small text}, and $\setminus$\texttt{small} is closed but this is still small
\item This new item is still small although no \texttt{$\setminus$small} used 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:
[image]

Appreciate so much if you can show me how to fix this.

Comment: You can use `{\small <your text>}`

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding that `\small` (and the similar commands) take an argument: they don't, but specify some setting to hold till the end of the group they're in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is improperly used: not `\small{this is small text}`, but `{\small this is small text}`.